# Embed function inside of IF statement Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, timestamp

This function works well, thanks to Michael the Temp.  But how can it work if embedded inside of an IF statement like so:  =IF(B2>5, TIMESTAMP(), "FALSE")

```
function TIMESTAMP() 
 {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   //Optional if you only want the date: var addedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
   //Optional if you only want the time: var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss");
   sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(addedDateAndTime)
   }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

hey @user17712179 welcome!
you can try this:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    //Optional if you only want the date: var addedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    //Optional if you only want the time: var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss");
    if (sheet.getRange("B2").getValue() > 5) {
        sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(addedDateAndTime);
    } else {
        sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue('FALSE');
    };
}
```

Let me know!

Comment: One additional requirement is that it is "one and done," meaning that once it inserts the date, it does not run the IF statement again.  I realized this requirement a few hours I asked for help.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also make AJ formula more reusable by adding params to the custom function and passing cell data to your formula.

```
 /**
 * Convert cell value in timestamp
 *
 * @param {cell} input The value to convert.
 * @return Timestamp converted.
 * @customfunction
 */

function TIMESTAMP(cell) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if (cell > 5) {
    return addedDateAndTime
  } else {
    return 'FALSE'
  };
}
```